# arranging table

Tags: tables

can someone help me fix the table

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\def\arraystretch{5}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm}| p{3cm} | p{6cm} |  } 
\hline 

Option& Laminar flow \break Re $\leq$2000 &Transition zone 2000$<$Re$\leq$4000 & Turbulent flow \break Re$>$4000\\ 
\hline
Colebrook-White &$f=f_l=\frac{64}{Re} $& $f=xf_t+(1-x)f_l$ & $f=f_t=\frac{0.25}{\bigg[log\bigg(\frac{k}{3.7D}+\frac{5.74}{Re^0.9}\bigg)\bigg]^2}$ \\ 
\hline
Hazen-Williams &$ f=f_l=\frac{64}{Re} $ &$f=xf_t+(1-x)f_l $&$f=f_t=\frac{1014.2Re^{-0.148}}{C_{HW}^{1.852}D^{0.0184}}$ \\ 
\hline
Fixed&f&f&f\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: So what do you want to change?

Comment: If you run the code you can see that there is an unnecassary gap between transition zone,and the formulas are not well fit in the cells I would be appreciate it if you can help me solve these problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your table is to wide for used text width. you should increase it
- `\arraystretch` doesn't work well, rather add vertical spaces as enables macro `\makegapedcells` from the package `makecell`
- for nicer fraction i suggest to use `\mfrac` defined in the package `nccmath`
- all `p{...}` column type i would replace with `l`
- for column headers i would use macro `\makecell` from the package with the same name
- it is not clear which shape for "Re" is correct: italic or upright (in code i consider the late
- result:

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

- i would increase text width with use the package `geometry`. in this case table is nice fitted in text width:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \usepackage{nccmath}

    %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
    \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
    %---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l |  }
        \hline
    Option  &   \makecell{Laminar flow\\ $\mathrm{Re}\leq 2000$}
                &   \makecell{Transition zone\\ $2000<\mathrm{Re}\leq4000$}
                    &   \makecell{Turbulent flow\\ $\mathrm{Re}> 4000$}  \\
        \hline
    Colebrook-White
        &   $f=f_l=\mfrac{64}{\mathrm{Re}}$
            &   $f=xf_t+(1-x)f_l$
                & $f=f_t=\mfrac{0.25}{\Big[\log\Big(\mfrac{k}{3.7D}+\mfrac{5.74}{\mathrm{Re}^0.9}\Big)\Big]^2}$ \\
        \hline
    Hazen-Williams
        &   $f=f_l=\mfrac{64}{\mathrm{Re}}$
            &   $f=xf_t+(1-x)f_l $
                &$f=f_t=\mfrac{1014.2\mathrm{Re}^{-0.148}}{C_{HW}^{1.852}D^{0.0184}}$ \\
        \hline
    Fixed   & f & f & f \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

**edit:** corrected inconsistency in use of `\mfrac` and added is missed `\end{document}`

Comment: Firstly,thank you for your effort.I tried your solution but it is still not fixed in my texmaker.My version is Texmaker 5.0.2.Do you have any advices about how could I fix this.

Comment: i don't use textmaker, so in anything about it i can't help you. it shouldn't have any influence on compilation of given code. try to compile this code in `www.overleaf.com/latex/templates`. code is tested by miktex (recent version)

Comment: I appreciate all your work Its done and fixed thank you very much.

Comment: @safag96, i edit my answer and correct some inconsistency in use of `\mfrac`. also is added missed `\end{document}`. sorry if the last made some inconvenience in testing of my answer. if you liked and if it solve your problem, you can accept them (by clicking on the check mark at the top left corner of the answer).